# Where do I attach C-Wire in this Rheem RBHA-24J11NUBAI system

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image][image]I'm installing an ecobee lite thermostat to this system and the c (blue) wire was hidden inside the wall, tracing the c wire inside the air handler I see that is not connected. I have tried connecting it to ground (rheem chasis) as per another post as well as to the brown and red wire but the ecobee does not work. Anyone knows where it goes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show where the other wires are connected?

Comment: I've added the image, I also added how it was connected to the original thermostat. I wonder if the issue is also with the red cable only being connected to the RH port in the ecobee as I can see a jumper connected both the RH and RC on the original thermostat. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The pictures say it goes to the brown wire. (same brown wire that goes to the outdoor unit)  Do you have a second thermostat?  where does the red-white-green cable go? (this cable has green unused)

Comment: You have red, white, yellow, and green at the thermostat.  But the (presuambly) other ends appear to be nutted to a variety of other wires.  Can you trace those to where they connect?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Huesmann for all the help the solution ended up been connecting at the brown wire and red wire but on the ecobee thermostat side the red wire needed to be at the RC port for this to work. Hope this help anyone else who may have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to confirm your answer! Please be sure to click the check mark (I believe you have to wait 24 or 48 hours) to help others know that this question has a confirmed solution.